# circular border-radius artifacts in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using react and have a circle component that I want to map on the screen. The problem is at certain view sizes I get small artifacts in the circles. Flat ends and only on certain rows of circles.

[Circles have flat sides at view width 980px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YldV1.png)

[ball hitbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDIV4.png)

[container hitbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai7G3.png)

```
.ballholder{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background-color:rgb(206,35,212);
    padding:0.5vw;
    border-radius: 5%;
    border:2px solid black;
}
.aball{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, whitesmoke, rgb(150,150,150));
    color:black;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    width:2vw;
    height:2vw;
    padding:0.05vw;
    margin:0.20vw;
    font-size:1.3vw;
}
```

Here's the parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Ball from "./Ball";
import "../App.css";

export default class Ballswitch90 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    const balls = this.state.balls.map((a, i) =>
      a ? (
        <Ball p={{ num: i + 1, clicked: false }} />
      ) : (
        <Ball p={{ num: i + 1, clicked: true }} />
      )
    );
    return <div className="ballholder">{balls}</div>;
  }
}
```

Ball component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom"
import '../App.css'

export default class Ball extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            num:props.p.num,
            clicked:props.p.clicked
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.clicked
                ?
                <div className="aball">{this.state.num}</div>
                :
                <div className="aballred">{this.state.num}</div>
            }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried adding a padding and margin but that only changed the size at which the flats show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the css rules with height and width make some problems.

You can see this snippet that works well:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/n6jrm1k2l

```
aball {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid darkred;
  padding: 1em;

  /* Center the text contents */
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  color: black;
}

.aball:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;

  /* Ensure the element is a square */
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.aball__value {
  /* Set the height to 0 and overflow to visible to not interfere with the square styles */
  overflow: visible;
  height: 0;

  /* Vertically center text since we set its height to 0 */
  margin-top: -1em;
}
```

Comment: @MinuteJavaScript happy it helps, please approve the answer so others could see that as well. Thanks